# How to categorize the word "schwifty"

Tags: adjectives

In one of the episodes in the TV-Show "Rick and Morty", Rick uses the word "[schwifty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ctK1aoWuqY)" when he is singing.

Obviously, this is just a made-up word. But my question is how is such a made-up word categorized? For example, I know some would argue that it is a "neologism". However, it is not really an accepted or mainstream word yet. So I assume it has to be called something else.

Comment: Here I think many people would call that a [_nonce_ word.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe a "[Nonce Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonce_word)"? In the sense that it has a meaning that the listener can guess at, despite not existing before.