# Term for a word "nollie"

Tags: terminology

In skateboarding, a nollie, short for "nose ollie", is an ollie executed at the front of the board while the rider is positioned in his/her natural stance.

Is there a term for those kind of words? Words that are not official English words? Not sure how to describe this and I don't think this is slang.

Comment: This may be essentially the same question as [one about *shwifty*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508558/how-to-categorize-the-word-schwifty) which I'm not really convinced should have been closed.

Comment: From your description it’s a portmanteau and also jargon and a  neologism. Which type of term were you looking for?

Comment: Basically, I'm interested/looking for words that don't "exist" in official dictionaries but they are in use, and also sound nice like nollie. So all those terms are correct I think. Portmanteau and neologism less jargon or slang maybe. I wish there would be a list of all those words but I understand to keep such a list would be impossible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word seems to be "jargon"

MW:

> **jargon** noun
>
> **1 : the technical terminology or characteristic idiom of a special activity or group**
>
> sports jargon

Or, in your case, skateboarding jargon.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewis_Marnell)

> Marnell executes a "switch frontside flip" at the Melbourne Museum location, described as "gnarly" (skateboarding jargon for something that is extraordinarily good ...)

More informally, skateboarding talk/speech/language.

Comment: Looking at terms mentioned by Jim, I think I'm looking for portmanteau and neologism and less jargon or slang.

Comment: Many portmanteau words are acceptable in English: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_portmanteaus, but some have a restricted currency. Those that only some use (a sociolect) are jargon.